# Android layout animation transition

Tags: android, animation, layout

im really sorry for asking but im really new in android and i want to achieve this animation in a layout transition
https://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4
i´d tried to make my own anim resourse

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100"/>
<scale
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXScale="0.95"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.95"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%p"
    android:pivotY="50%p" />
<alpha
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

but cant get that smooth and nice result
if someone can point to me to the right direction ill appreciate that

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html  Please check out this document .You are looking for SharedElement transition .

Comment: oh.. i really appreciate this, i did it but what im looking for is the animation entrance and exit just like the vid, maybe i should change the title, im really sorry, this is my first question :(